# dropping a row with at least one value larger than a particular value

Tags: matrix, pattern-matching, list-manipulation, data

So for instance I have M X N table. I want to drop any row which has an element larger than, say, one in the second or the third column.

I guess I have to do some sort of pattern matching. But not exactly sure how to do it. I can use a table to search for a value and then find its Position and then drop the corresponding row. There must be a easier way to do this without traversing through each element using the Table function. help please :)

Comment: Per my comment to *Kguler*, could you clarify: do you mean in your example any rows with columns other than second or third with a value greater than the second *or* third, or are you interested in only checking against one column?

Comment: Sorry for this late response and the confusion. I meant second or third column (for that matter any column) containing a value which is larger than a particular value (e.g. 10, etc). Your suggestion is very exciting.

Comment: OK, I'm actually more confused re-reading your OP and reply. Say a row is {1,2,3,4,5,6,7} (element is col number in this case). Is it that you want to specify some value, and then remove rows where only certain columns you specify have a value exceeding that, or is it you want to specify some columns, and delete any rows where any of the *other* columns in the row have a value exceeding any of the values in the specified columns (what I answered)?

Comment: I went ahead and updated my post with the alternative interpretation... let me know if that's what you meant.

Comment: I want to specify some value, and then remove rows where only certain columns I specify have a value exceeding that.

Sorry for all the confusions! the other interpretation of my OP sounds too complicated :). But then I am not sure I was clear

Comment: Now I'm puzzled - you accepted an answer that does not do what you said you want - nowhere there is a value specified to check against. I'm deleting my answer as noise since I clearly don't understand what you're after. Sorry for confusing the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 refcol = 3;
 dt = RandomInteger[10, {10, 5}]; 
 dt//TableForm
```

[image]

```
Select[dt, Max[# - #[[refcol]]] <= 0 &]
(*   {{2, 7, 8, 5, 4}, {7, 1, 8, 4, 0}, {4, 10, 10, 3, 6}} *)
```

Alternatively,

```
DeleteCases[dt, _?(Max[# - #[[refcol]]] > 0 &)]
Cases[dt, _?(Max[# - #[[refcol]]] <= 0 &)]
Pick[dt, (Max[# - #[[refcol]]] <= 0) & /@ dt]
```

all give the same output.

Showing the deleted rows in red:

```
If[Max[# - #[[refcol]]] > 0, Style[#, Bold, Red, 20] & /@ #, 
          Style[#, Directive[Bold, 20]] & /@ #] & /@ dt // TableForm
```

[image]

**Update:**  The four functions above work for the case of a single reference 
column.For the case where a row is deleted if any entry exceeds any 
of the multiple reference column entries, one needs the following 
straightforward modifications:

```
 f1 = Function[{dt, cols}, With[{rest = Complement[Range@Length@dt[[1]], cols]}, 
          Pick[dt, (Max[#[[rest]] - Min[#[[cols]]]] <= 0) & /@ dt]]];
 f2 = Function[{dt, cols}, With[{rest = Complement[Range@Length@dt[[1]], cols]}, 
         Select[dt, Max[#[[rest]] - Min[#[[cols]]]] <= 0 &]]];
 f3 = Function[{dt, cols}, With[{rest = Complement[Range@Length@dt[[1]], cols]}, 
         Cases[dt, _?(Max[#[[rest]] - Min[#[[cols]]]] <= 0 &)]]];
 f4 = Function[{dt, cols}, With[{rest = Complement[Range@Length@dt[[1]], cols]}, 
         DeleteCases[dt, _?(Max[#[[rest]] - Min[#[[cols]]]] > 0 &)]]];

 f1[dt, {2, 3}] == f2[dt, {2, 3}] == f3[dt, {2, 3}] == f4[dt, {2, 3}]
 (* True *)

 f1[dt, {2, 3}]
 (* {{2, 7, 8, 5, 4}, {4, 10, 8, 0, 4}, {4, 10, 10, 3, 6}} *)
```

Comment: Am I missing something? How does this handle checking against multiple "target" columns as per the OP? Unless I misread the meaning of "...one in the second *or* the third column..." (emphasis mine).

Comment: @rasher, obviously no -- this does not check against your interpretation of "say,  ... or ..." :) Let's wait for OPs clarification.

Answer (score 0):

This is significantly faster than other options presented:

```
Pick[dt, Max /@ dt - dt[[All, refcol]], 0]
```

Timings:

```
refcol = 3;
dt = RandomInteger[10, {50000, 7}];

Select[dt, Max[# - #[[refcol]]] <= 0 &]         // Timing // First
DeleteCases[dt, _?(Max[# - #[[refcol]]] > 0 &)] // Timing // First
Cases[dt, _?(Max[# - #[[refcol]]] <= 0 &)]      // Timing // First
Pick[dt, (Max[# - #[[refcol]]] <= 0) & /@ dt]   // Timing // First
Pick[dt, Max /@ dt - dt[[All, refcol]], 0]      // Timing // First
```

> ```
> 0.1372
>
> 0.1652
>
> 0.1592
>
> 0.1716
>
> 0.02932
> ```